# Use two repositories in same directory and act like a middleman

Tags: git, github, gitlab

How can I achieve the following git setup?

I have two Git Repositories with the same project but different people working on it. Every change that someone makes in repository 1 should be shown as my change in repository 2 and the other way around. Changes that I do myself should be represented as mine in both repositories.

I'm new to git and tried several approaches from online but nothing gave me the results I described above.

Comment: Why are they different repositories?! Sounds like you want just one.

Comment: On the first repository are working Junior Devs and I have the responsibility to check everything they commit until I push it into the real repository as my change. In the real repository the accounts of the Junior Devs shouldn't be visible.

Comment: You setup 2 remotes on the local repo and then you can interact (fetch/pull/push) into either one.

Comment: Having two repos isn't rare, btw. You often have one locally on your machine and one on a remote server, e.g. an Github or Gitlab. BTW: Those services already provide features to make code reviews easy and they can be configured so that not everybody can commit to protected branches. Sounds to me like you're trying to re-invent already existing cooperation practices.